# NestedScrollView fix the view top inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to fix the `TabLayout` on top when scroll-like Instagram. Is there a way to do this in the `NestedScrollView`?

```
NestedScrollView
-- ConstraintLayout
---- OtherViews
---- TabLayout
---- ViewPager
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE4FL.png

https://gist.github.com/buraktabn/c73cd04bed6a223471834756d6f32773

Comment: Can you attach an example of your actual layout?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
ConstraintLayout
-- OtherViews
-- TabLayout
-- NestedScrollView
---- ViewPager
```

That way the content of the ViewPager will scroll? FYI It may also be worth looking at the `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) which will allow users to regain some of their screen back when scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly within the `NestedScrollView` because the view itself is supposed to scroll content.

If you're looking for a fixed `TabLayout` at the top that doesn't move, you can pull the `TabLayout` out of the `NestedScrollView` and encompass both of these views under another layout type (eg. `LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc).

If you want the a `TabLayout` that expands and contracts as the user scrolls, your best bet is a `CoordinatorLayout` which can encompass a `NestedScrollView` and then implement your `TabLayout` under the `CoordinatorLayout`'s `AppBarLayout`/`CollapsingtoolbarLayout`. The structure would look similar to:

```
CoordinatorLayout
- AppBarLayout
-- CollapsingToolbarLayout
--- [Your implementation of the `TabLayout`]
-- NestedScrollView
```

You can find more information on `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` here:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout
- https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/
- (a simplified intro) https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/